# Proper replacement for compile dependency

Tags: scala, gradle

This is part one of my little question series regarding gradle-driven pure scala projects. <s>More coming up the next days.</s> Edit: Given the bad reception of this question I will at least have to rework them before posting them.

A few weeks ago I started a new private scala project that I wanted to build with gradle. IDEs tend to have enormous startup times on my system that don't scale if I just want to do some minor edit. So I chose gradle because I knew it already (with sbt being an option for me, too). This lets me use an IDE, too, in case I really need a larger set of tooling but a command line is all I need most of the time.

The latest version that I had installed was some version 2.x (which still worked well for some time), I then quickly upgraded to a more recent 5.x and - partially to test out the new plugins-syntax - the last days I also took a look at 6.0. This latest version gave me deprecation warnings because of compile dependencies in my build scripts. Using version 6.0 has more or less doubled my build-times so I won't use it unless I really need some of the new features, but the deprecation warning still applies even (if not even more) when using gradle 5.x.

No problem, I thought, as the gradle-runtime already suggests how to fix them. But this simple replacement of compile with implementation couldn't work out, as I was (ab-)using the transitivity of compile dependencies in my code. Then I has hoping for others having the same issue. And there are and plenty of them gave plenty of guides to solve this. Unfortunately, none applied to pure scala-projects. For android seems to be an obvious solution with api dependencies. Java projects can make use of the java-library plugin (which probably is the basis for the mentioned android project solution, too) with the api dependency. But for scala there is no such way, or at least I haven't found it.

So, to be clear: I have a multi-project setup here and I only struggle with dependencies to other sub-projects. Not with dependencies to external sources. And replacing runtime (for external libs) and testCompile dependencies was no problem at all.

So, here's my question: Is there a proper/canonical way to replace compile dependencies in pure-scala projects? (While I wasn't especially happy with using 'official' in one of my own comments hours ago, what about this point of view: Regardless of who initially created the scala plugin (scala-team, scala-community, gradle-team, or gradle-community), the gradle-team decided to include it into their distribution back then and now the gradle-team decided to mark compile dependencies deprecated. Shouldn't then the gradle-team also have an **official** opinion about how to continue maintaining scala-projects?) Or is there no common recommendation and I'm left with the choice between these options that are all not optimal for whatever reason:

1. Stick with compile dependencies. Definitely **not future-proof** in the long run.
2. Unfold all transitive dependencies and add new (technically unnecessary) ones. If A depends on B and B on C (and A actually uses definitions from C), add a dependency from A to C, too. **Bloats dependency graph and build scripts**.
3. Apply the java-library (to non-application projects) although I manage scala projects just to have an api dependency. Both, java-library and scala, extend the java plugin so I expect no real harm here. Probably the best solution although I'm not sure if adding a whole new plugin for a single dependency type is the right choice. And **adding any 'java'-thing to 'scala'-projects seems odd**.
4. Reinvent the wheel, somehow, and define my own api dependency. This seems to be the ugliest way given that I had to **copy some code from the gradle-repository** into my own project. That's what plugins are for, isn't it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) for why this kind of subjective question is not appropriate.

Comment: I admit, I haven't read this particular guide-line before, but could you elaborate, why you think this is subjective? Sure, I made some suggestions but just to help others to understand what I already taken into account. This isn't meant as a multiple-choice-quiz and I don't want to see which answer is given the most. There has to be some official answer/solution to my problem, hasn't it? And this answer is what I am looking for.

Comment: Just what is the question here ? And all of these are heavily subjective because these choices depends the choices you make in your `.gradle` files. Gradle allows such a high level of flexibility that making objective statements is not possible for most real world gradle projects. What works for your gradle build for same problem might not work (or even be considered absurd) for the other gradle build.

Comment: Even more, I dislike each of the provided 'options' (at least partially) and I clearly stated why for each. So I'm especially looking for some totally different approach. Or some evidence, that there is no such 'proper' solution and gradle is treating scala programmers not as welcomed as - say - android developers.

Comment: Gradle is not making any developers feel welcomed. The android plugins (and guidelines) were developed by android developers and google. So, if the Scala developer community chooses, they can devote 2-3 years to create ecosystem of plugins and guidelines. And this is exactly what android community did... it was not easy, android + gradle used to be a fragile puzzle in  2013-2014, it became as good after years of improvement.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh so you say, while there is ONE official solution for java (the java-library plugin) if you want to prevent any deprecation, for scala there isn't and it's just my choice of which of these poor approaches I want to make for my project? That answer would be all I was looking for, if this is the case.

Comment: Although I have not tried it before. I don't see any reason that you won't be able to use java-library-plugin in a scala project.

Comment: It's not about ability here. I am able to (use any of the mentioned approaches e.g. to) recreate my own api-dependency and I am able to put nails into walls using screwdrivers instead of a hammer. And I haven't wanted to blame gradle solely. Everyone can create plugins so if there are no sufficient scala-plugins both the scala community and gradle are more or less responsible.

Comment: I tried to formulate the question more objective. Hope this helps anyone to tell me that there isn't. ;) But given that there is/was **by far** more than one question on compile dependencies for android and none for scala, I'm wondering why you somewhat debase this question (which could become a go-to question for scala developers and perhaps cause improvements of the scala plugin eventually) and aren't spending more time on marking all the android questions duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply apply the `java-library` plugin and use `api`. Think about the plugin as a Java *platform* library plugin, not a Java *language* library plugin.

Note that to be fully functional, you will need at least Gradle 5.6 otherwise some wirings are not complete.

Comment: That I've expected somehow, so thanks nonetheless for a somewhat official answer. You pointed at version 5.6. Is this due to [issue 9872](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/9872)? And what about [issue 8788](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/8788) limiting me to at least 6.0 that shows bad performance for me? Or does this only apply if I apply scala and java-library to different projects? I would have a scala+java-lib project depend on another scala+java-lib project.